# annotation based autowiring can never give multiple results even though it is by type

Tags: java, autowired, springsource

My question is:

In a web application where I use context component scan rather than writing bean in xml,the beans are created automatically so if in a class I write @autowiring it's implicitly by type and there can never be multiple results in this case, which may normally occur if I use xml way of declaring like

My understanding is that in xml format when I repeat multiple beans with same class it's instantiated only once but value/property value differ each time as classes are singelton implicitly.So when I autowire in that case springs is confused which bean I am talking about but in annoations as beans are created by there own this scenario will never occur.

Is the understanding correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Correct, it is done by class. If you need to autowire several beans of the same class then you can use the

```
@Component(value="someName")
```

And then select the bean you want with

```
@Qualifier("someName")
@Autowired
```

Comment: you can also use @Primary to mark primary classes that should win out in case of multiple hits on an autowiring